# HAL STM32 Uart Receive Interrupt: Reset Receive Buffer Problem

Tags: c, stm32, uart, interrupt-handling, stm32f4discovery

I work with mcu STM32F407VGT6 ,ide STM32CubeIDE. Right now I'm examining some basic operation and I'm little confused about how works uart in interrupt mode when receive data. I will explain what I don't understand: mcu receive some data from terminal, after that mcu do something with that data, and finally I want to "reset" receive buffer. Buffer isn't 1/2 or full filled, thats is ok for my puropse now. So imagine buffer is filled less then 1/5.

`

```
while(1){
     if(HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3, rxBuff, strlen(rxBuff)) != HAL_OK)
     {
            Error_Handler();
     }
     HAL_Delay(3000);
     temp = rxBuff[0];    
     if(HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart3, rxBuff, strlen(rxBuff)) != HAL_OK)
     {
            Error_Handler();
     }
}
```

`

Comment: We will ned more information. What is your question? What do you expect? And what does/doesn't happen? Did you initialize the UART and the interrupt?

Comment: Take a look at this question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087338/receiving-a-string-through-uart-in-stm32f4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63087338/receiving-a-string-through-uart-in-stm32f4), it seems to be very similar.